# CSS Slider -- firing keyframe on each slide

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to have an element slide in a few seconds after each slide on my CSS slider. The animation is currently only happens on the first slide.   Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
keyframes top {
from { top: 0; right: -250px; }
to   { top: 0; right: 100px; }
}
.top {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: top;
}
```

Here's full demo of what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/tekgirl/zcm2w6e1/

P.S. I'd like the element to stay at 100px mark instead of bumping all the way to the left.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but it sounds like `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` might help for the PS part.

Comment: do u use any js plugin for slider? u need to see the function when starting new slide and inside of that function u add class with animation to your element and when slider finish u also must to have a function that will remove the class added, in that case u will manage to make animation on each slide intro.

Comment: I am not using any jquery or javascript. There is no way to accomplish this without it?

Comment: Would love more help with this...